# $X_n \nrightarrow 0$ in $L^1$ implies $X_n \nrightarrow 0$ in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

I have a sequence of RV for which I can proof $$\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\,\mathbb{E}[ X_n]=-C<0 $$ and $$\mathbb{E}[ X_n]=-C<0 $$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and a certain $C>0$.

From there on we find
$$ C=|\mathbb{E}[X_n]|\leq \mathbb{E}[|X_n|] $$
and I think it is safe to say that also $C\leq \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]$ if the RHS exists, which is $X_n$ does not converge in $L^1$ to $0$. Now we can conclude $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\, \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq C)>0$ by contradiction. Suppose
$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq C)=0 \Rightarrow\mathbb{P}(|X_n| < C)=1\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[|X_n|]<C$$ and $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}$ on both sides proves the statement.

This means the sequence $X_n$ does not converge in probability to $0$.

The first question is do you think this is a valid proof or is there a mistake?
The second question is if $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\,\mathbb{E}[ X_n]$ diverges because it has 2 finite accumulation points $$\underset{l_1 \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\,\mathbb{E}[ X_{n_{l_1}}]=-C_1<0 $$ and $$\underset{l_2 \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\,\mathbb{E}[ X_{n_{l_2}}]=-C_2<0 $$. Can I still argue the same way?

Comment: that $\mathbb{E}[X_n]=-C$ for all $n$ doesn't mean that the sequence diverges in $L^1$. By example, it can be the case that $X_n\equiv -C$ almost surely for every $n$ so the sequence converges to $-C$ in all senses

Comment: Yeah you are right, my question was not about divergence so I edited it out. I simply want to show that $0$ is neither the limit in $L^1$ nor in probability.

Comment: You showed that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \ge C) > 0$ for all $n$, but this doesn't show $X_n$ fails to converge in probability.  For example, we might have $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \ge C) = \frac 1n$ for all $n$.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$ has two finite accumulation points but the limit is the same for both of them - doesn't that mean there is only one accumulation point?

Comment: I want to prove the $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\,\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq C)>0$ the same way I proved $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq C)>0$. Suppose $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\, \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq C)=0 \Rightarrow \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\, \mathbb{P}(|X_n| < C)=1\Rightarrow \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\, \mathbb{E}[|X_n|]<C$, contradiction. You are right with the accumulation points I'll edit the correct statement.

Comment: You can't prove a false statement. Suppose $(A_n)$ is a sequence of events such that $\mathbb{P}(A_n)>0$ for all $n$ and $\mathbb{P}(A_n)\to0$. Then fix $C>0$ and define RVs $(X_n)$ by $$X_n=-\frac{C}{\mathbb{P}(A_n)}\mathbf{1}_{A_n}.$$ Then $$\mathbb{E}[X_n]=-C\quad\text{for all }n,\qquad\text{but}\qquad X_n\to0\quad\text{in probability}.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you!